# CQWP: zero likes displays null, zero comments displays 0

Tags: sharepoint-online, content-query-web-part

I have followed this guide

[SharePoint 2010 Content Query](http://erikswenson.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/sharepoint-2010-content-query-for-blog.html)

Everything works including adding the number of likes (internal name LikesCount). I see side by side Number of comments and number of likes, when there are zero comments it displays 0. When there are zero likes it displays nothing. The 2 fields seems alike, but behave this way, is there an easy way to have 0 displayed also for zero likes?